# Do you like hats? (2013 Edition)

Tags: discussion

Last year around Christmas time we had an awesome promotion in which hats for for gravatars were awarded for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* again because we all love hats, right? right?

But to get this awesome hat promotion we have to **opt in**. That means acting on this meta post, whether that's voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments and/or just directing positive energy this direction.

I think this is a good chance at a bit of harmless fun, that could potentially help keep site traffic up through the northern hemisphere winter (when traffic usually dies down a bit for us).

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion. Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out).

---

Due to unanimous support, we will have hats! Thanks for voting!

---

(Majority of content blatantly stolen from [freiheit](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76/freiheit)'s copy of [waxeagle](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/wax-eagle)'s [post on meta.christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/do-you-like-hats).)

Comment: "Upvote this post for free hat".  I can't quite decide whether this is a cunning way to get rep or a cheeky reference to a certain episode of South Park!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

And I would wear them in a boat!
And I would wear them with a goat...
And I will wear them in the rain.
And in the dark. And on a train.
And in a car. And in a tree.

(Yes hats)

[image: No eggs and ham]

Answer (score -2):

I would not like them here or there.
I would not like them anywhere!

(No hats)

[image: No hats]